What does it mean for a ring to be non-integrally closed?
I learned some basic examples of integrally closed domain from algebra course, for instance, consider the ring
$$
k\left[x,y\right]/\left(x^{2} - y^{3}\right)
$$
where $k$ is an algebraic closed field, such as $k=\mathbb{C}$.

The professor told me that "intuitively", the reason that integrally closed property fail to hold is that, there is a cusp in the algebraic curve $y^{2} = x^{3}$.
However, in another of his example $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{5}\right]$, it is also
not integrally closed ( consider $\alpha = \left(\sqrt{5} - 1\right)/2$, for instance ), however he said nothing about why this ring is "bad".

So I'm here looking for some intuition. Thanks in advance.

The intuition on the first ring is linked to the geometric counterpart being a curve on an algebraically closed field, for which the "regularity" (having cusps/nodes or not) is equivalent to integrality of the ring (in some sense made precise by algebraic geometry). This intuition no longer holds so clearly, either for varieties of higher dimensions, or when we are no longer working over a field. Maybe a close inspection of Serre's criterion for normality can give geometric insight in the case of $\Bbb Z [\sqrt{5}]$... ?

$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is "bad" because it is not a Dedekind domain and hence fails to have unique factorization of ideals. Explicitly, $(4) = (2)^2 = (\sqrt{5} + 1)(\sqrt{5} - 1)$. In the integral closure $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$, these factorizations are no longer different, as $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ is a unit.

See here on MO for some relevant geometric intuition (and here for more explanation of the pushout construction).

Here's another related MO post that tries to make explicit the analogy between the geometric and number theoretic settings.

One intuition I like has to do with orders of vanishing and uniqueness of limits.
Suppose $R$ is an integral domain and $K$ is its fraction field. Most elements of $K$ have a good reason to not be in $R$: they have poles, i.e. they “evaluate to infinity” at some points of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. For example $t/(t-1)^2\in k(t)$ has a double pole at $t=1$. In general there is a well-defined notion of order of vanishing $ord(f)$ for an element $f$ of a one-dimensional local noetherian ring, namely the length of $R/(f)$. And this extends to fractions by $ord(f/g) = ord(f) - ord(g)$, and to general noetherian rings $R$, for each height-1 prime ideal $P$, by evaluating the orders of elements in each $R_P$ separately.
Notably, elements of $R$ have nonnegative orders in $R_P$ for all height one prime ideals $P$. Contrapositively, if $h \in K$ has a negative order in some $R_P$, then $h$ can’t be in $R$.
Unfortunately, sometimes there are elements of $K$ that aren’t in $R$, but “not for any good reason” - they don’t have any poles. For example, on the cuspidal cubic $R = k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$, $y$ vanishes to order $3$ and $x$ to order $2$ at the origin. (You can see this explicitly here since the normalization is $k[t]$ where $y = t^3$ and $x=t^2$.) So it’s obvious that $x/y$ can’t be in $R$, since it has a pole at the origin. But $y/x$ is not in $R$ either, and it doesn’t have a pole - anywhere!
More generally, if $h \in K$ satisfies a monic relation $h^d = r_0 + r_1 h + \cdots + r_{d-1} h^{d-1}$, then $h$ can’t have negative order $ord(h) = -e<0$ because the left-hand side would then have a pole of order $de$, and the right hand side a pole of order at most $(d-1)e$.
It is a theorem (the "algebraic Hartogs lemma") that normality is equivalent to $R = \bigcap R_P$, the intersection ranging over all height-one prime ideals. That is, normality means that elements of $K$ are in $R$ if and only if they have nonnegative order at every $P$.
As for what the existence of "an element with no poles, but $\notin R$" means geometrically in the non-normal case, I actually think the problem is clearer to see using the nodal cubic rather than cuspidal cubic, $R = k[x,y]/(y^2 - x^2(x+1))$. Both $y$ and $x$ have order $2$ at the origin $x=y=0$, so $y/x$ does not have a pole at the origin. The normalization is the ring $k[t]$ where $y = t^3-t^2$ and $x = t^2-1$, and the two preimages of the node are $t = \pm 1$. The reason the function $y/x = t$ is not in $R$ is that, even without a pole, it doesn't have a well-defined value at the origin, because it approaches two distinct limits, $t \to \pm 1$, along the two branches! So we are detecting the fact that the curve self-intersects.
In the cuspidal case, something instead goes wrong with the derivative of the function. Something like, the function doesn't have a well-defined derivative at the origin, or its derivative vanishes even though the function only has a simple zero.
In your number field situation, something similar is happening: the element $\alpha = (\sqrt{5} - 1)/2$ has nonnegative order everywhere (by integrality), so in some sense it shouldn't really count as a fraction... despite the apparent denominator of $2$.
